# ¿Es correcto o seguro combinar código vba con fórmulas en la hoja de cálculo de Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Quisiera saber cómo analizar la siguiente situación para saber si es seguro trabajar de ese modo, dado que no conozco el flujo de la ejecución.
Supongamos que tengo una hoja de cálculo y un Form, o macros en general.

En la **hoja de cálculo** tengo:

- A1 (valor de la celda): 10
- A2 (valor de la celda): 20
- A3 (fórmula): =A1+A2

En parte de mi **código vba** tengo:

```
Dim MiSuma as Integer
Range("A2").Value = 30
MiSuma = Range("A3").Value
```

La pregunta es, ¿es seguro asignar un valor a una celda (A2 en el ejemplo) y, en la instrucción inmediatamente posterior, usar el resultado de una fórmula para, por ejemplo, asignar el valor de una variable?
La fórmula podría en realidad ser más complicada que una suma. Lo hice varias veces con fórmulas de búsqueda o cosas por el estilo, y siempre funcionó, pero no estoy seguro si en alguna ocasión podría estar asignando el valor antes que el resultado de la fórmula sea evaluado.

Edición: Agrego que trato de analizar el tema independientemente del alcance de la variable. Cuando hablo de **independencia del alcance de la variable**, me refiero a que no me interesa mantener el valor. Supongamos que dentro del ámbito en el que mi variable existe (en este caso `MiSuma`), yo uso su valor para actualizar un registro de una base de datos, llamar a una función y pasarla como parámetro o actualizar otra celda, entre otros ejemplos.
Por ese motivo, digo que me interesa solamente saber si la operación que hago en la instrucción `MiSuma = Range("A3").Value` puede ser considerada "segura", teniendo en cuenta que el valor de `A3` depende de una cela que fue modificada en la instrucción anterior.

Por otro lado, estas planillas fueron desarrolladas en versión 2013 y luego usadas también en 2016. No encontré ningún problema, en realidad siempre funcionaron bien, pero esto no implica que sea necesariamente siempre así. De ahí nace la pregunta, entender si puedo hacerlo una práctica habitual o conviene evitarlo.

Por último y para resumir. Dicho en un modo poco técnico, sería interesante saber si si Excel "llega a tiempo" a calcular la fórmula antes de que yo la use en la línea sucesiva. Por otro lado y contrariamente a lo anterior, imagino que en realidad `"=A1+A2`" es una función, y que al invocarla, solo basta con que los valores de `A1` y `A2` hayan sido establecidos, ya que al pedir "dame A1+A2", si los valores de `A1` y `A2` fueron seteados, naturalmente la suma será correcta. Realmente no sé con qué enfoque quedarme

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sin saber mas de lo que estas haciendo, esta pregunta podria considerarse basada en opiniones. Habria que ver que mas se hace por codigo, o cual fue la idea original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Consideraciones

La pregunta es interesante, porque bajo condiciones normales debería poderse y menciono lo anterior, porque es posible desactivar los cálculos automáticos en excel, esto básicamente por temas de rendimientos [Configurar el Cálculo Automático de Fórmulas en Excel](https://exceltotal.com/configurar-el-calculo-automatico-de-formulas-en-excel/)

Adicionalmente, a veces también es necesario desactivar los cálculos automáticos, cuando se realizan [Simulaciones de Monte Carlo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Montecarlo) para flujos de cajas de proyectos y se quiere que el gráfico tornado ([inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_diagram)) así como otras variables (tasa de retorno, saldo final, etc.) no cambien una vez hecha la corrida.

Lo anterior se hace necesario porque **Excel** no dispone de un generador de semilla para números aleatorios -[Random Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)- como otros programas -[setting seed for excel random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161114/setting-seed-for-excel-random-number/33170115)- si bien hay soluciones para ello, eso escapa ya a la pregunta.

Continuando con las excepciones si se estuviera haciendo referencia al valor de una tabla dinámica -[Crear fórmulas en una tabla dinámica](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/calcular-valores-en-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77)-, y se decide cambiar alguno de los datos que la está generando, estos no se reflejará automáticamente a menos qué se [actualice dicha tabla dinámica](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/actualizar-los-datos-de-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-6d24cece-a038-468a-8176-8b6568ca9be2).

Creo que esas serían -si no todas- las principales causas por las cuales una fórmula no se vería actualizada automáticamente, sí los datos que las alimentan son cambiados, dentro de una hoja de cálculo o archivo **Excel**.

Con respecto al código, por el momento no cuento con **SO Windows**, entonces no quiero incluir código sin haberlo probado, no obstante, hay que tener presente que **VBA** tiene tres alcance para sus variables:

1. Ámbito de procedimiento (local)
2. Ámbito de módulo
3. Ámbito público

Recomiendo verse más en detalle sobre el [ámbito de las variables en visual basic para aplicaciones](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)

En tal sentido, asumo por el código posteado que:

```
Dim MiSuma as Integer
```

Corresponde al primer ámbito (local), en ese caso, si no se está en ninguna de las excepciones previamente señalas, al ejecutarse la **macro** se llamará primero la línea `Range("A2").Value = 30` ésta acción, está actualizando la hoja en cuestión.

Por tanto al ejecutarse la segunda línea `MiSuma = Range("A3").Value`, la variable local `MiSuma` debería ser `40`, pero tener presente que al ejecutar nuevamente la macro: *se reinicializan todas sus variables locales, ya que las variables permanecen en existencia sólo mientras se ejecuta el procedimiento en el que se declara.*

## Sobre la respuesta

A mi entender la pregunta podría capitalizarse también de la siguiente manera:

> ¿Es recomendable combinar fórmulas de **Excel** con **VBA**?

Sobre lo anterior, al leer este artículo: *Dos Maneras de Aumentar la Velocidad de las Macros en Excel* ([inglés](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-speed-up-excel-macros/)), se menciona qué dependiendo la complejidad del programa, se puede mejorar el rendimiento de la **Macro**, sí se realiza lo que expuse al inicio de mi respuesta... **desactivar los cálculos automáticos**:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Lo anterior implica que las `fórmulas`, dependiendo su complejidad podrían tomar un tiempo en actualizarse, haciendo que las sentencias de la **Macro** se retrasen para estar acorde a los valores que se vayan actualizando en la hoja o libro de **Excel**.

En tal sentido, uno podría decantarse por rendimiento, en ese caso ya no sería seguro usar las fórmulas, pero si quieres estar seguro, pierdes rendimiento, entonces todo va depender de que se quiera lograr.

Finalmente, en esta artículo *Nueve (9) Consejos Rápidos para Mejorar el Rendimiento de una Macro en VBA* ([inglés](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/9-quick-tips-to-improve-your-VBA-macro-performance/td-p/173687)), se proporciona también, unos códigos que pueden ayudar a mejorar el rendimiento de la **Macro**, qué desde mi punto de vista, es a lo que se aspira en cualquier programa, indistintamente el lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En realidad mi pregunta apunta a algo más conceptual, quisiera independizarme del alcance de la variable. Es decir, se deberá analizar el flujo del programa en las sucesivas ejecuciones. Por eso, centraba mi análisis entre las líneas 2 y 3. Dicho en un modo poco técnico si Excel "llega a tiempo" a calcular la fórmula antes de que yo la use en la línea sucesiva.

Comment: Perdón, pero me faltó una parte. Dicho en un modo poco técnico, sería interesante saber si si Excel "llega a tiempo" a calcular la fórmula antes de que yo la use en la línea sucesiva. Por otro lado y contrariamente a lo anterior, imagino que en realidad "=A1+A2" es una función, y que el invocarla, solo basta con que los valores de A1 y A2 hayan sido establecidos. Realmente no sé con qué enfoque quedarme.

Comment: Hola @Mati creo que la pregunta quizás podría capitalizarse si fuera... ¿Es recomendable combinar fórmulas de **Excel** con **VBA**? Al leer este artículo [Two ways to speed up Excel macros](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-speed-up-excel-macros/) mencionan que dependiendo la complejidad del programa, para mejorar el rendimiento de la macro, es recomendable hacer lo que expuse al inicio de mi respuesta `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, eso implica que las formula dependiendo su complejidad

Comment: podrían tomar un tiempo en actualizarse, haciendo que las sentencias de la macro se retrasen para estar acorde a los valores que se vayan actualizando en la hoja o libro de Excel. En tal sentido, uno podría decantarse por rendimiento, en ese caso ya no sería seguro usar las fórmulas, pero si quieres estar seguro, pierdes rendimiento, entonces todo va depender de que se quiera lograr

Comment: Adicionalmente en esta página [9 quick tips to improve your VBA macro performance](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/9-quick-tips-to-improve-your-VBA-macro-performance/td-p/173687) proporcionan también unos códigos que pueden ayudarte a mejorar el rendimiento de la macro, qué desde mi punto de vista, es a lo que se aspira en cualquier programa, indistintamente el lenguaje de programación.